# Validating A form and then passing onto a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to validate a simple form, but somehow it's not happening. I need to validate the form at the client side ( server side - I'm able to do, but that's not efficient ) and then pass it onto a php file for necessary action.

The code that I'm trying thus far is:

**abc.js**

```
$("#makeproj-nav").click(function()
{

s = "<div class='create_project_card'><div class='new_project_title'><span>New Project</span></div>";

// project form starts

s += "<form id = 'create_new_form' name = 'new_form' method='post' action='insert_new_project.php'><div class='project_form'><span>";

s += "<div class='Form_contents'> <div> Project Name: <input type='text' size='100' name='project_name'></div>";

s += "<div class='Form_contents'> <input type='submit'> </div>";
s += "<span></div>";

$("#card-wrapper").html(s);

$('#create_new_form').on('submit', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var x = document.forms["new_form"]["project_name"].value;
if (x==null || x="")
        {alert("Not Valid"); return false;}
    else
{
$.ajax({
      url : 'insert_new_project.php',
      type : 'POST',
      data : $(this).serialize(),
      success : function(response) {
 $("#card-wrapper").html(response.reply);
          }
        });

}

});

});
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: put `var self = this;` at the start of the submit-handler, and then in the success-function `self.submit();`

Comment: wait, maybe I'm missing something... you don't actually want to submit the form, just send the data with AJAX?

Comment: hey, first I want to validate, then submit the form and receive the response from the php file to display on the page all inside that ajax function.